# Power BI desktop count value occurance in some columns of one table

Tags: powerbi

Here is the table looks like:

```
       column 1    column 2   column3
row 1  Peter       sedan      truck
row 2  Jim         sedan      SUV
row 3  Tom         van        sedan
row 4  Andy        truck      SUV
```

What I want to count is how many cars have been owned: 
Expected result:

```
sedan 3
Van   1
Truck 2
SUV   2
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is this for a visual? If yes, then what column do you intend to list all the vehicles?

Comment: It is for a visual. New column or new table. Switching from Cognos to Power BI, not sure what kind of method need to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be much easier if you unpivoted `column 2` and `column 3` (in which case, you could do a simple count on the resulting column), but it's possible with this layout as well.

Create a new table that combines columns 2 and 3. For example,

```
Vehicles = DISTINCT(UNION(VALUES(Drivers[Column2]), VALUES(Drivers[Column3])))
```

And then place that table's only column on a table or matrix visual and write a measure to count. Something like this:

```
VehicleCount =
VAR CurrVehicle = MAX ( Vehicles[Column2] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        COUNT ( Drivers[Column2] ),
        FILTER (
            Drivers,
            Drivers[Column2] = CurrVehicle || Drivers[Column3] = CurrVehicle
        )
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will try to play with it.